# How to capture, save, and rebroadcast an infrared signal?

Tags: wireless, infrared, remote-control

I need to capture a signal that is being sent from an emitter (similar to a TV remote). I understand from [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/106701/looking-to-capture-an-infared-code) question that I can use an infrared receiver to do this.Once this is done, however, I need to be able to continually rebroadcast this signal even when its original source is not broadcasting. Is there a way to save this signal, or does in need to be decoded in some form to be rebroadcasted without the original? How might I go about doing this?

Comment: That answer has the signal demodulating/decoded. If you use a microcontroller, you save that input, and then just continually send it out again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an IR library for arduino that is pretty good: [Arduino-IRremote](https://github.com/z3t0/Arduino-IRremote)

A guide on how to use it: [A Multi-Protocol Infrared Remote Library for the Arduino](http://www.righto.com/2009/08/multi-protocol-infrared-remote-library.html)

It is capable of recording and replaying a lot of common remotes. The wiring is very easy, a simple device is described here: [An Arduino universal remote: record and playback IR signals](http://www.righto.com/2009/09/arduino-universal-remote-record-and.html)